# XMPPFramework in podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xmppframework, podspec

Previously, I integrated XMPPFramework by using dependencies in `podspec: s.dependency 'XMPPFramework', '3.6.6'`

I'm aware that in order to fix the error of 'Redefinition of module dnssd'. We should pod directly from the master branch:

`pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'`

Unfortunately, we cannot use dependencies without version, so I commented the dependency out and used pull XMPPFramework using podfile. I fixed some minor issues and was able to build the app, but when I tried to do `pod spec lint` I got the following error:

```
- NOTE | xcodebuild: PHMessaging/PHMessaging/Classes/PHMessagingManager.h:20:9: fatal error: 'XMPP.h' file not found - NOTE | xcodebuild: PHMessaging/PHMessaging/Classes/PHBasicConversationViewController.h:10:9: fatal error: 'XMPPFramework/XMPPUser.h' file not found
```

I've already raised [the issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6212) with CocoaPods on GitHub, and @BenAsher44 suggested to create a private specs repo and add it to the dependencies in my podspec. This didn't seem to work. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Is it similar to [what I did here](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/blob/master/Podfile)?

Comment: No it's not that I have multiple targets, but I can't import XMPPFramework using my podspec.